# Conversao entre Decimais e Binarios em um vetor, com elementos gerados aleatoriamente

Tags: java, conversão, binary

Preciso fazer um programa onde 10 numeros gerados aleatoriamente que são armazenados em um vetor, são convertidos para binário e mostrados para o usuário. *Não necessariamente* precisarão ser armazenados em um vetor.

Só que não consigo fazer um loop fazendo isso.

Consegui no máximo montar esse algoritmo que faz a conversão de um único número, mas fora isso não estou conseguindo, nem eu, nem meus colegas que tentaram me ajudar.

Vale dizer também que eu tinha feito usando o metodo `toBinaryString`, mas isso faz parte de uma lista de exercicios, e nosso professor quer que façamos a mão, sem ficar utilizando muitos recursos.

Segue aí o código que eu fiz, porém, não consigo o encaixar em um for loop.

```
int decnum, aux, i=1, j, cont=0;
int binnum[] = new int[100];
Random any = new Random();

decnum = any.nextInt(10)+1;
aux = decnum;
while(aux != 0)
{
    binnum[i++] = aux%2;
    aux /=2;
}

System.out.print("O numero equivalente em binario de " + decnum + " é :\n");
for(j=i-1; j>0; j--)
{
    System.out.print(binnum[j]);
}
```

Comment: Podemos usar de funções/métodos para resolver isso? Ou precisa resolver na `main`?

Comment: Precisa ser na main, porque como o professor não ensinou métodos, ele julga que não sabemos e, sendo assim, não podemos usar.